# Consulta ao Firebase realtime database não retorna os valores alterados no banco

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho uma consulta no Firebase que deve retornar os dados do usuário para verificar se este ainda tem acesso e o seu nível de acesso ao sistema, no entanto ao modificar os valores a consulta continua trazendo os valores anteriores.

```
private void buscarUser(String matricula){
    ValueEventListener buscaUserListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(BuscaUserPage.this,
                        "Usuário não encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                try {
                    Usuario userRecebido = null;
                    for (DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        userRecebido = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);
                        idUser = dados.getKey();
                    }
                    atualizarTela(userRecebido);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(BuscaUserPage.this,
                            e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(BuscaUserPage.this,
                    "Ocorreu um erro: " + Objects.requireNonNull(databaseError),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };


    Query consulta = referenciaFirebase.child("Usuarios").orderByChild("matricula").equalTo(matricula);
    consulta.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(buscaUserListener);
}
```

Classe Usuario:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String email;
private String senha;
private String matricula;

private int nivelAcesso;
private boolean ativo;
}
```

Os valores de nivelAcesso e ativo que são alterados.

Comment: Você activou a Offline Persistence do Firebase?

Comment: A persistência offline está ativa.

Comment: É por isso que você está tendo esse problema. Pode ser que esteja levando muito tempo para carregar os novos valores, ou esteja havendo algum problema com a sua conexão. Esse problema é meio comum quando usamos a persistência offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema realmente estava ligado a Offline Persistence do Firebase. Estava utilizando este código para ativar a persistência:

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}}
```

Então substitui essa classe por um singleton que utilizo em apenas algumas activities em que é interessante manter a persistência off line.

```
public static DatabaseReference getReferenciaFirebaseOffLine(){
    if(referenciaFirebase == null){
        bancoFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        bancoFirebase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        referenciaFirebase = bancoFirebase.getReference();
    }
    return referenciaFirebase;
}
```